# on SSH login, get message 'Could not chdir to home directory"

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I am SSHing into a Mac OS X server running Tiger.

When I log in I get put in the root directory and shown this message:

```
Could not chdir to home directory : No such file or directory
```

My `$HOME` variable seems to be empty. I've googled the problem and found a mailing list thread which suggests using `dscl` to set up the home directory, but I've done that and the problem still persists even though now `dscl` correctly reports:

```
$ dscl . -read /users/me NFSHomeDirectory
NFSHomeDirectory: /Users/me
```

Comment: two ideas: a] is your user living in local or LDAPv3 directory? b] do you have a login shell set for the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up a mobile user with a local home on that 10.4 server.
To do this, log into the server as an admin then run the following commands:

```
$ cd /System/Library/CoreServices/mcxd.app/Contents/Resources
$ sudo ./MCXCacher -U accountname
$ sudo createhomedir -c -u accountname
```

Running those commands will first tell the MCXCacher program to create a mobile user in NetInfo with cached credentials, and then the createhomedir program will make a home folder in whatever place you have set to be the folder that houses your homes. Your user account will then get correctly sent to its local home folder after logging in via SSH, and single-sign-on with Kerberos will also work just fine.